# typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>,

Tags: ios, swift, struct

my JSON :

```
'''
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "widgets": [
      {
        "type": "small_half_slider",
        "data": {
          "banners": [
            {
              "id": 42765,
              "image": "",
              "title": "!",
              "is_ad": false,
              "url": {
                "url": "",
                "page": "web_link",
                "params": {
                  "url": ""
                },
                "queries": []
              },
              "video": "",
              "description": "",
              "bullet_points": []
            }
'''
```

and my Struct:

```
'''
import Foundation

struct mainPage:Codable{
  var  status:Int?
  var  data: mData?
}

struct mData:Codable {
    var widgets:[Mwidg]
}

struct Mwidg:Codable{

    var type:String
    var data:wdata
}

struct wdata:Codable{
   var show_type:String?
   var banners:[bannerData]?
}

struct bannerData:Codable {
    var id:Int?
    var image:String?
    var title:String?
    var is_ad:Bool?
    var url:urlData?
    var video:String?
    var description:String?

}
struct urlData:Codable {
    var url:String?
    var page:String?
    var params:paramsData?
    var queries:[queriesData]?
}  

struct paramsData:Codable {
    var url:String?
}

struct queriesData:Codable {

 }


'''
```

then i faced to this error:

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "widgets", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Well, apparently the value type of the key `data` in the **second** element of the array `widgets` is array and not object. Check your JSON. Does it have `{...}` or `[...]` as it's value?

Comment: Paste your JSON into [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) to see what it builds a struct to see if you will help find the spot you have wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because in your json response you are not getting values or getting nil values for properties which are present in struct mData and Mwidg, to work your solution make struct properties as optional so that even if you didn't receive data in your json response the code will work. The json you pasted in question is not completed and it may possible that you were getting some object as nil.